# ZEND - decorators and position of elements?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

I've got a problem with zend decorators and can't figure out how to place an element in form where i want to have him.

I got a form where decorators are putting my data into a table, but i want to have my submit out of the table. For now i have something like that:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
    $select = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('article' . $i);
    $select->setAttrib('style', 'margin-top:10px;width:200px;');
    $select->addMultiOption('1', $this->translate->_('Zatwierdzony do druku'));
    $select->addMultiOption('0', $this->translate->_('Niezatwierdzony do druku'));
    $select->setValue($rows[$i]['reviewed']);
    $select->setDecorators(
      array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array(
          array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), 
          array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'padding5 tdcenter')
        ), 
            array(
                'AnyMarkup',
                array(
                    'markup' => $this->_getMarkupForRow($i, $rows),
                    'placement' => 'PREPEND',
                )
            ),
        array(
          array('row' => 'HtmlTag'),
          array('tag' => 'tr', 'openOnly'=>true)
        ),
      ),
      array('submit'),
      false
  );
  $this->addElement($select);
}

$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('updatetoprint');
$submit->setAttrib('id', 'updatetoprint');
$submit->setLabel('Zapisz');
$submit->setDecorators(
   array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array(
      array('data' => 'HtmlTag')
    ), 
    array(
      array('row' => 'HtmlTag'),
      array('tag' => 'div', 'closeOnly'=>true,'style' => 'float:left;')
    )
   //here i dont know how to get my submit on the bottom under the table...?
   ), 
   array('submit')
);
$this->addElement($submit);
```

On site that looks like this:
[image: my form]

And i'd like to have my submit on the bottom under the table... Please help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see where you are assigning your form to the view or if your form is a Zend_Form or not so I'm going to make some assumptions.
I'm going to assume you are using Zend_Form to build your form and I'm going to assume you are assigning your form to the view in the traditional manner inside a controller action
 `$this->view->form = $form;`
So with that being said, in your view script you have access to each individual element simply by
 `<?php echo $this->form->elemenetName ?>`
 where elementName is the name you have given your element in your case your submit button has the name ***'updatetoprint'***.
With this in mind if you need to create a table or any other layout you could simply create generic elements in your form and just add them as needed to any view script. Might prevent you from performing all those gymnastics with decorators.

For example view.phtml might look like:

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->form->getAction() ?>" method="<?php echo $this->form->getMethod() ?>">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Dodal</th>
        <th>Tutyl</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    <!--you should probably put the next 5 lines into a partial and use partialLoop($data)-->
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->form->dodal ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->form->tutyl ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->form->status ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <?php echo $this->form->updatetoprint ?>
    </form>
```

Then just style with css.

To setup the form to use the viewscript just use:

```
$form->setDecorators(array(
    'PrepareElements',
    array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'form.phtml')),
));
```

where form.phtml is your viewscript name

[Edit]
After further consideration I realized that diplaying form elements in this manner has one serious drawback. The form is never initialized...the *form* tags are never sent. This edit is to correct that issue.
Sorry it took so long

Comment: Indeed, an intermediate approach between decorator gymnastics (ha!) and putting form elements into your view script is to simply use a Viewscript decorator. This is especially useful if you use the form in multiple places in your app.

Comment: @David Weinraub That's one thing to really love about ZF there is almost always many different solutions to a problem. I haven't explored the Viewscript decorator yet, but I'm sure I will have a reason to at some point.

Comment: still havin problem to get data to partial and dont know how to get that stupid anymarkup into it...damn i hate ZF DECORATORS... its sick:(                              EDIT: i just made id displaying some other method but i dont know how to make it to be a form (i can manually add form tag but its not a good solution i think... cause when i am making it by your method and adding viewScript (maybe im doing it wrong) my submit button is not active and i can not sbmit changes. and my css on page is messing up and everything is changed (bad) i dont know how to do it...

Comment: actually i'm plenty sure there is an option to get that submit down... It must me possible :( i'm fighting with it for a long time and i'm desperated and sad and mad... :(:(:( i'm using it in module and using a view helper as you see above to assign it to index.phtml file... i dont have any idea how to pass it correctly... pojebane to...;/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest adding all your elements apart from the submit button to a display group. You then give the display group a HtmlTag decorator (with the tag set to table), which will wrap all your elements with a table, making your HTML valid and giving you the layout you want.

Comment: i was trying with no result... I don't know where i am making a mistake.. but displaygroup wasn't working...

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing lots of `<tr>` and `<td>` tags, but no `<table>` tag. What I think you are looking for is markup roughly like this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>info</td><td>more info</td><td>select element</td></tr>
    <tr><td>info</td><td>more info</td><td>select element</td></tr>
    <tr><td>info</td><td>more info</td><td>select element</td></tr>
</table>
<div>
    <input type="submit">
</div>
```

What seems to be missing from your code are any decorators that produce the `<table>` and `</table>` tags. So, on the first iteration of the loop, use the AnyMarkup decorator to prepend a `<table>` and your header row. On the last iteration, add a decorator that appends the `</table>` tag.

Then your submit button (which is added last) should sit right underneath.

Comment: the table tag is in my phtml file cause i need headers like Dodał, Tytuł etc which are added manually in phtml. Thats whym table tag is out of the form. When i was making table tag inside form it wasn't working actually too... effect was the same as above. Yes i want to have structure as you described above. But if i made table tag inside form how to manually add headers like Dodał, Tytył and Status etc.. i don't know how to do it...

Comment: Well then that's the essence of the problem: if your view-script script contains the open/close table tags with the form in between, then there is no way for the submit button *in* that form to appear *outside* that table. I'd push the table rendering into the form which is actually easier since you are already familiar with the  AnyMarkup decorator. I'll update the answer.

Comment: i know how to get table tag inside the form script but if i do this i dont knot how to still have headers of the tables. Waiting for your update of answer:)

Comment: @DarAss: It already updated the answer, but I admit, it was a pretty subtle update. ;-) The upshot is this: On the `$i == 0` iteration of your loop, use the AnyMarkup decorator to prepend the opening `<table>` _and_ your header row. On the `$i == $count - 1` iteration, use the AnyMarkup decorator to append the `</table>`. See what I mean?